# Install Firefox extension with automatic script

Tags: firefox, ubuntu, firefox-addon

I'm trying to install an extension for Firefox in Ubuntu, either globally or for a specific Ubuntu user or for a specific Firefox profile - doesn't matter which. I've tried the solutions posted in older threads but they don't work for the Firefox version (20.0) right now. I've tried various solutions and none of them have worked.

Does anyone know of a command/script that can do this?

Thanks!

Comment: What did you try?  Did you try the method outlined at [Installing extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Installing_extensions)?

Comment: Yeah, I tried all of those, both global and user specific, and both as an .xpi or extracted. Firefox just seems to ignore what I do; the extension list does not show my extension.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are using firefox for some scripts / bots or a resource hungry website and you have an old computer? I recommend installing RamRUSH as an add-on - with the number of frames below 8% it automatically optimizes memory and firefox is more stable

Personally, I also used the trick: about: config

```
browser.sessionstorage = 0;
browser.sessionstory = 0;
cpd.history.enabled = false;
```

This relieves the browser a bit and is more stable

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The core reason why it didn't work was because my extension itself was faulty.

The solution to do it is to put the Firefox extension (an .xpi file) under `/usr/share/mozilla/extensions/{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}/`.